# What are the guarantees on React lifecycle event order between components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, lifecycle

What are the guarantees on React lifecycle order across separate components, and are they clearly documented anywhere?

For example, given I have:

```
<div>{ x ? <A /> : <B /> }</div>
```

Here, `x` changing between true & false will unmount one component and mount the other.

Are there *guarantees* about the order in which lifecycle events involved in the mounting will fire across these elements?

For example, it's [well documented](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) that `render` for A will fire before `componentDidMount` for A when `x` changes to true. However, is it guaranteed that `render` and `componentDidMount` for A will always fire after `componentWillUnmount` for B?

To take this further: does it change if A and B are children further down in this tree, with the switch at the top?

Any answers welcome, but firm documentation on this very much appreciated.

Comment: While there are no guarantees listed anywhere in the docs, based on my trial it seems upon state update i.e. `x` updates to false, `B` gets called and its `constructor` and `render` method runs after which `A`'s unmount happens. Both are isolated components and not sure what is your fear on having individual lifecycle run at any given time. Say it as even unmount dont happen before another components mount why would it matter as React's reconciliation is not going to care about component going in unmount cycle

Comment: In my case, for unrelated reasons I'm making direct DOM changes on mount/unmount, and A & B _aren't_ isolated from one another - they both edit the same DOM. If willMount for B runs before didUnmount of A, my code can fail. I'm going to try to make that more resilient, but it would be easier to do so with some idea on the possible orderings here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the tests inside React's official repo, you can easily find the relevant tests related to this order.

- [Github -- React-Mounting-Tests -- Test **File**](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-dom/src/__tests__/ReactCompositeComponent-test.js)
- [Github -- React-Mounting-Tests -- Test **Line**](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/f6efb224b091a741fad1bc7916b5936ff91f85fe/packages/react-dom/src/__tests__/ReactCompositeComponent-test.js#L1486)

---

```
 it('prepares new child before unmounting old', () => {
    const log = [];

    class Spy extends React.Component {
      UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
        log.push(this.props.name + ' componentWillMount');
      }
      render() {
        log.push(this.props.name + ' render');
        return <div />;
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        log.push(this.props.name + ' componentDidMount');
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
        log.push(this.props.name + ' componentWillUnmount');
      }
    }

    class Wrapper extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <Spy key={this.props.name} name={this.props.name} />;
      }
    }

    const container = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper name="A" />, container);
    ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper name="B" />, container);

    expect(log).toEqual([
      'A componentWillMount',
      'A render',
      'A componentDidMount',

      'B componentWillMount',
      'B render',
      'A componentWillUnmount',
      'B componentDidMount',
    ]);
  });
```

> **The reasoning behind this implementation can be found** @ [commit
>   message for test](https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/ba8f24ba9937c6cec70e4cb00aa2ded02f7d5cdc)
>
> "This matches what we do in Fiber -- and doing it this way is the only
>   way we can prepare new views in the background before unmounting old
>   ones."

---

Also check this recent changelog for React 16.0.0 : [React 16.0.0 changelog](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)

```
When replacing <A /> with <B />, B.componentWillMount now always
happens before A.componentWillUnmount. Previously,
A.componentWillUnmount could fire first in some cases.
```

So this order is guaranteed!

Comment: Great answer, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidUnmount` is never called in conditional rendering.

I tested on [codepen](https://codepen.io/minion/pen/jONjqqv?editors=1111) and get the result like below:

**Parent component**

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      flag: false,
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { flag } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 onClick={() => this.setState({flag: !flag})}>CONVERT</h2>
        <div>
          { flag ? <A /> : <B /> }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Child Component A**

```
class A extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('A is mounted');
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('A will be mounted');
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('A will be unmounted');
  }
  componentDidUnmount() {
    console.log('A is unmounted');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>A</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

**Child Component B**

```
Almost the same as A :D
```

**Result**

I clicked on `CONVERT` twice and the result was:

```
"B will be mounted"  // first render
"B is mounted"

"B will be unmounted" // first click
"A will be mounted"
"A is mounted"

"A will be unmounted" // second click
"B will be mounted"
"B is mounted"
```

> `componentDidUnmount` was never called in conditional rendering.

Comment: I actually made a mistake in the question - I meant: will didMount for A always happen after willUnmount for B, not didUnmount. The ordering here is still useful though, thanks! Do you know of any sources or documentation for this? I'm really to find the overall guarantees & invariants here, rather than specific examples.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I had a difficult time understanding the fundamental differences between the componentWillMount() and componentDidMount() methods. I kept getting frustrated when one would work, yet I didn’t understand how or why.

componentWillMount()
One big snag that I didn’t realize until an online study group session is that componentWillMount() was deprecated in 2018. While you can continue to use it (until React 17.0), it isn’t best practice because it is not safe for async rendering. If you do choose to continue to use it, you should use UNSAFE_componentWillMount().

The Reason
Using a fetch call within componentWillMount() causes the component to render with empty data at first, because componentWillMount() will NOT return before the first render of the component.

Due to the fact that JavaScript events are async, when you make an API call, the browser continues to do other work while the call is still in motion. With React, while a component is rendering it doesn’t wait for componentWillMount() to finish, so the component continues to render.

With all that being said, you would need to to create a component that still looks presentable without the data that you are hoping to display. There is no way (not even a timer) to stop the component from rendering until the data is present.

When I was building my project, I didn’t know about the deprecation of componentWillMount() and I didn’t understand why I kept getting the “cannot read property ‘map’ of undefined” error. I was so confused because I had an array and it should be getting populated by data, but it wasn’t.

Turns out this makes complete and total sense since the component is rendered with empty data at first, so the array was empty and couldn’t be iterated over. It was only at this point that I learned that it is best practice to use componentDidMount().

componentDidMount()
The best place to make calls to fetch data is within componentDidMount(). componentDidMount() is only called once, on the client, compared to componentWillMount() which is called twice, once to the server and once on the client. It is called after the initial render when the client received data from the server and before the data is displayed in the browser. Due to the fact that the data won’t be loaded until after the initial render, the developer NEEDS to set up the components initial state properly.

On a side note, with componentDidMount() you can use a timer and have the data updated every so often without the user ever having to refresh the page. I’d say that is a really neat feature that can be useful in projects/websites.